# Invoke Media Player in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, media, media-player

Is there is a way to invoke a media player in BlackBerry ?
If so, can we also pass a url to the player asking it to open and stream a remote url file?

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about invoking the standard media application or just embed player in your app?

1)If you want to embed player check this - http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Playing-Audio-in-Your-Application/ta-p/446826

2)If you need to start the standart bb player you can use the Content Handler API(CHAPI). Look around and you will find many tutorials. Basically it works like this: you have a .mp3 file for example and you make request to the blackberry os asking "can anyone handle .mp3 extension" , and if there is an app registerred to handle mp3 you can invoke it automatically and i handles tha fore/background transitions between your app and the mp3 handling app.

Comment: Hi Gosho , Thanks , I am more interested in the latter solution, We have a media file that is hosted on a http server, currently we are calling the borwser to open and play the file using the BrowserSession class , however I would want to call the native api player and pass the url directly, Thanks for you help...